# Need help getting this page nav working correctly

Tags: pagination, plugin-wp-pagenavi

For some reason the page nav doesn't work correctly. It's styled odd on the [home page](http://noahsdad.com/), then if you go to [a page](http://noahsdad.com/page/2/) you'll see it really looks odd.

I can't figure out what's happening. If anyone has any ideas I'd appreciate it. Thanks.

Here is the code from my pagination.php

```
<?php if( is_single() ) { ?>

    <div id="single-post-nav" class="row">

        <?php $pagination_width = 'full_width_layout' == $options['layout'] ? 'span6' : 'span4'; ?>

        <?php previous_post_link( '<span class="' . $pagination_width . ' previous-page">%link</span>', _x( '&larr; %title', 'standard' ) ); ?>

        <?php if( '' == get_previous_post() ) { ?>
            <?php next_post_link( '<span class="' . ( $options['layout'] == 'full_width_layout' ? 'span12' : 'span8' ) . ' no-previous-page-link next-page">%link</span>', _x( '%title &rarr;', 'standard' ) ); ?>
        <?php } else { ?>
            <?php next_post_link( '<span class="' . $pagination_width . ' next-page">%link</span>', _x( '%title &rarr;', 'standard' ) ); ?> 
        <?php } // end if/else ?>

    </div><!-- /#single-post-nav -->

<?php } elseif ( $wp_query->max_num_pages > 1 && ( is_home() || is_archive() || is_search() ) ) { ?>

    <div id="post-nav">
        <ul class="pager">

            <?php if( get_next_posts_link() ) { ?>
                <li class="previous">
                    <?php wp_pagenavi(); ?>     
                    </li>                   
            <?php } // end if ?>

            <?php if( get_previous_posts_link() ) { ?>
                <li class="next">
                    <?php wp_pagenavi(); ?>
                </li>
            <?php } // end if ?>

        </ul><!-- /.pager -->
    </div><!-- /#post-nav -->

<?php } // end if/else ?>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't have a code issue, just CSS. In your default.css, just at the end, add this:

```
#menu-under-header .navbar-inner ul{clear:both !important; width:1000px;}
.menu-header-container{clear:both !important;}
#social-networking{clear:both !important;}
```

and that's it. You may want to add a position for social networking. IN that case, replace the last line with this:

```
#social-networking{clear:both !important; position:relative; left:760px;}
```

**EDIT: SEE THE FOLLOWING THEN:**

first of all, it seems like you're calling you pagenavi twice. And yes, you still have CSS issues, see below to correct:

```
.wp-pagenavi span.pages{clear:both !important; text-align:left !important; margin:5px !important;}
.wp-pagenavi a.larger, .smaller, .previous, .last, .nextpostslink, .previouspostslink{width:auto !important; padding:20px !important;margin-top:15px;}
```

so, just check your page template for that additional call to page navi, add the CSS fix and lmk if it works out

Comment: Thanks for your help. But this is with the top nav. I'm talking about the page nav (at the bottom.)

Comment: I included the page template in my code above and I can't see the additional call to page navi. Am I missing something? (I replaced the previous and next with the page nai) Should that only be there once? Also the css you left above is different than the first css. Do I insert both? (thanks for your help by the way.) (Nevermind I see one of those is for the page nav and the other is for the menu)

Comment: the thing is that the code you added isn't related to what you're looking for, so really don't know what to tell you without seeing it. Could you paste your index.php code? You can use pastebin.com if needed . My bet is you'll have a conditional for home page and a faulty code for the remaining pages

Comment: thanks for your help. It looks like the wp_pagenavi is in there twice. (it replaced the next and previous post link.) I'm assuming I need to take one of those out, right? Here's the pastbin to the index.php. http://pastebin.com/f8Krx8Yk

Comment: by the way, here is what the pagenation.php looked like before i replaced it with the call to wp_pagenavi http://pastebin.com/zPFtR5KY

Comment: And here are the instructions of how to install the page navi plug in: "
In your theme, you need to find calls to next_posts_link() and previous_posts_link() and replace them.

In the Twentyten theme, it looks like this:

<div class="nav-previous"><?php next_posts_link( __( '<span class="meta-nav">&larr;</span> Older posts', 'twentyten' ) ); ?></div>
<div class="nav-next"><?php previous_posts_link( __( 'Newer posts <span class="meta-nav">&rarr;</span>', 'twentyten' ) ); ?></div>
You would replace those two lines with this:

<?php wp_pagenavi(); ?>"

Comment: hey Rick, here's the issue: you have 2 pagination systems at the same time. One is internal, the other is for pagenavi. So, what you have to do is open pagination.php and replace everything from lines 25 to 35 with the pagenavi code. That should work (although you should make a backup first) . If you still have issues, try using wp-paginate plugin (see it at http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/wp-paginate/ ), it's easier and less buggy than wp-pagenavi

Comment: Thanks for your help, I think I got it all working well. You mind giving it a quick check to see? Oh by the way, I used the css for the menu up top, but wasn't sure if I still needed for the page nav. Thoughts?

Comment: well, you still have a couple CSS issues, but at least it's working fine now

Comment: any thoughts on how to get the css fixed up?

Comment: add the following at the end of default.css: `code`.wp-pagenavi span.pages, .current{color:#ccc; clear:both !important; text-align:left !important; margin:5px !important; padding:0 20px 0 0 !important;}
.wp-pagenavi a.larger, .smaller, .previous, .last, .nextpostslink, .previouspostslink{width:auto !important; padding:20px 15px !important;margin-top:15px;}`code`

Comment: I had to take off the CSS you gave me for the menu area. It didn't adjust correctly in the responsive design of my theme. Any thoughts on how to get it to respond correctly? Thanks.